# HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder causes web page to hang

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am new to JMeter and am trying to set up some performance tests.  I set a JMeter project that contains this:

1. Test Plan

   - Thread Group

     - HTTP Request Defaults
     - HTTP Cookie Manager
     - Recording Controller
2. WorkBench

   - HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder

     - Constant Timer

The issue I am having is that when I record a run the recording works fine until I reach a specific page.

I start my test script recorder, navigate to this page: https://www.lawdepot.com/contracts/loan-agreement/ and when I click the "Create My Document" button the page will be stuck on the loading screen forever.

Is there a way to figure out what is happening?  I checked the log view window and don't see anything helpful there.

Comment: Upon clicking on `Create My Document` there are three main calls happening `https://www.lawdepot.com/t.gif?ps=QSGeneralInfo&pg=QGPaymentType&cs=QSLocation&cg=QGGoverninglaw&lc=false&pc=BLOAN&r=50661` AND `https://www.lawdepot.com/contracts/loan-agreement/index.aspx` AND `https://www.lawdepot.com/contracts/DCSMain2.73/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl00_ctl02_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b`.

Comment: There are multiple variables for hanging. Solution is try in another browser or use Blazemeter Chrome Add-on or Smartmeter Recorder. Please check this link for more details:  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en and https://www.smartmeter.io/blog/improve-jmeter-script-recording-introducing-smartmeter-recorder

Comment: I am not sure why you added `constant timer` in Workbench. It is not required. Thanks!